# when does bounded subharmonic function be a constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I don't know why in 2-dimensional space, a subharmonic function bounded from above must be a constant while in higher dimensional space (when the dimension is larger than 2), the argument does not necessarily hold.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243898/what-is-the-counter-example